# How can I configure Android 12 so that my phone (Pixel 6) is screen mirrored when connected to a monitor via HDMI?

Tags: android-12, screen-mirroring, google-pixel-6

I'm  connecting my Android phone to a monitor via USB-C -> Hub -> HDMI cable:

[image]

My phone  Samsung Galaxy S9 screen is mirrored without any issue, but that  doesn't work with my Google Pixel 6. How can I configure Android 12 so that my phone (Pixel 6) is screen mirrored when connected to a monitor via HDMI?

I use this [Lasuney "Triple Display USB Type C" hub](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B082KMKQQX/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the grey dock that you're using is not compatible with Google Pixel 6. I don't know how to get a list of docks compatible with Google Pixel 6 though.

From https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2865484?hl=en:

> ### Project with a wired dock
>
> For a faster connection when you play games or compete in esports, use a wired connection. Certain wired docking stations are compatible with Pixel phones. On a compatible dock with an ethernet port, you can also connect to LAN.
>
> To set up and project on your Pixel phone, follow the steps that came with your compatible dock. For example:
>
> 1. On your phone, from the Play Store, install the [DisplayLink Presenter app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.displaylink.presenter).
>    **Tip:** When you connect your phone to the docking station, the app doesn’t need to be open.
> 2. With a USB-C cable, connect your Pixel phone to your compatible dock.
> 3. With an HDMI cable, connect your compatible dock to your monitor or TV.
> 4. Plug in your compatible dock's power cable.
>
> **Tip:** Pixel 3 and later Pixel phones work with the [MediaGear USB-C Hub Docking Station (item 853265008171)](https://www.mediagearpro.com/d1-w.html#/). Other docking stations can also work.